# What are popular addons on Bugzilla

Tags: scheduled-tasks, project-management, bugzilla

We are using Bugzilla for tracking of the bugs. We want to use addons for task tracking and for project management. There are a lot of addons for this purpose. Can any one please suggest the good addons for this purpose.

Also let us know any other addons that you know are good.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all addons for bugzilla in below link. Also check EZ!PM under project management addons. That seems to be good tough I am not using that -

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons